# pairs plot not downloading from shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, download

I am making a shiny app to display different kind of panelplots from several r packages.

The app works as expected expect when i try to download the plot. Every time i download one of plot it turns out empty or it cannot be opened.

I have been trying for days to get it working but no luck.
Hope anyone can help

```
ui.R
## Script setup

    library(ggrepel)
    library(grid)
    library(openxlsx)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)
    library(clipr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(stringr)
    library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset
    library(shinycssloaders)
    # Define UI for data upload app ----
    ui <- fluidPage(

      tags$style("
                 body {
                 -moz-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9); /* Moz-browsers */
                 zoom: 0.9; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
                 zoom: 90%; /* Webkit browsers */
                 }"),

      # App title ----
      titlePanel("Panelplot generator"),

      # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
      sidebarLayout(

        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(


          # Input: Select a file --
          fileInput("upload_bestand", "Upload Excel-bestand met data",
                    multiple = FALSE,
                    accept = c("xls",
                               "xlsx",
                               ".xlsx")),


          # Button
          #downloadButton("Download_Uploadsheet_Panelplot.csv", "Download Uploadsheet"),


          # A select input for selecting subset
          downloadButton("Jackknife.png", "Download Panelplot"),


          # Input: Checkbox wel of geen titel ----
          #checkboxInput("header", "Uploadsheet is inclusief titelrij", TRUE),


          # Horizontal line ----
          #tags$hr(),

          # Input: Decimaal  ----
         # radioButtons("sep", "Decimaalteken",
         ##              choices = c(Komma = ",",
          #                         Punt = "."),
         #              selected = ","),

          # Horizontal line ----
          tags$hr(),

          #Input: Plotkeuze  ----
          radioButtons("Plotkeuze", "Panelplot Model",
                       choices = c("Panelplot met alleen bovenreeks" = "Panel_boven",
                                   "Panelplot met onder- en bovenreeks" = "Panel_alles",
                                   "Panelplot met Correlatie coefficient" = "Panel_regres",
                                   "Panelplot met Correlatie-ellipsen" = "Panel_elips"),
                       selected = "Panel_alles")         



        ),


        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(



          # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
          tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                      tabPanel("Data upload", DT::dataTableOutput("data_upload")),
                      tabPanel("Data samenvatting", DT::dataTableOutput("data_sam")),
                      tabPanel("Panelplots", plotOutput("Panelplots",width = "100%", height = "800px")%>% withSpinner(color="orange")),
                      tabPanel("Handleiding App", tableOutput("handleiding"))
          )
        )
      )
      )
server.R
## Script setup

library(ggrepel)
library(grid)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(ggthemes)
library(lubridate)
library(shinythemes)
library(clipr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(skimr)
library(DT)
library(psych)
library(tools)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$data_upload <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({

    req(input$upload_bestand)

      inFile <<- input$upload_bestand

      if(is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

      keuze<-3

      tryCatch(

        data_raw <<- readxl::read_excel(input$upload_bestand$datapath,sheet = keuze),

        finally = print("Het bestand wordt niet herkend als .xlsx of .xls-bestand"))

      # Data aanpassen voor weergeven in app

        data_display <- data_raw

  }))


  # Data samenvatting----
  output$data_sam <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({

    req(input$upload_bestand)

    data_summ_raw_1<-skim(data_raw)

    data_summ_fin<-data_summ_raw_1[,-c(4,5)] %>%
      filter(type=="numeric") %>%
      filter(stat != "hist")%>%
      filter(stat != "p25")%>%
      filter(stat != "p75")%>%
      filter(stat != "complete")%>%
      spread(stat, formatted)

    colnames(data_summ_fin)<-c("Kolomnaam","Datatype","Gemiddelde","No. ontbrekende", "No. rijen", 
                               "Minimum","Maximum","Mediaan", "Standaard deviatie")

    data_summ_fin<-data_summ_fin[,c(1,2,5,4,3,9,6,8,7)]

  }))


  # Panelplot weergeven
  plotInput <- reactive({


    data_plot<-Filter(is.numeric, data_raw)

    if (input$Plotkeuze == "Panel_alles"){

      panelplot<-pairs(data_plot, pch = 19)

    } else if (input$Plotkeuze == "Panel_boven"){

      panelplot<-pairs(data_plot, pch = 19, lower.panel = NULL)

    } else if (input$Plotkeuze == "Panel_regres"){

      # Correlation panel
      panel.cor <- function(x, y){
        usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
        par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
        r <- round(cor(x, y), digits=2)
        txt <- paste0("R = ", r)
        cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
        text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)

      }
      # Customize upper panel
      upper.panel<-function(x, y){
        points(x,y, pch = 19)
      }
      # Create the plots
      panelplot<-pairs(data_plot, 
            lower.panel = panel.cor,
            upper.panel = upper.panel)

    } else if (input$Plotkeuze == "Panel_elips"){

      panelplot<-pairs.panels(data_plot, 
                   method = "pearson", # correlation method
                   hist.col = "orange",
                   density = TRUE,  # show density plots
                   ellipses = TRUE) # show correlation ellipses

    }

    panelplot

  })

  output$Panelplots <- renderPlot({

    print(plotInput())

  })

  # Template uploadsheet downloaden ----
  output$Download_Uploadsheet_Jackknife.csv<- downloadHandler(
    filename = "Uploadsheet_Jackknife.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      uploadsheet<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=4))
      colnames(uploadsheet)=c("Storingsno.","ComponentNaam","DowntimePerStoring","DatumStoring")
      str(uploadsheet)
      write.csv(uploadsheet,file,row.names = FALSE)
    })

    output$plot_down <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "iris.png", 
      content = function(file) {
        png(file)
        print(plotInput())
        dev.off()
      }
    )

}
```

Comment: I know every time I try to use the download function using the Rstudio browser, I have issues. Have you tried this in Chrome or some other browser?

Comment: Cory, yes i tried. Both in firefox and in explorer. Firefox downloads a html of the current webpage and explorer opens a blank screen for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the rationale behind it, but changing the plotInput from a reactive to a static function and insert that into the output$panelplots did the trick